# overwrite existing file excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
open_book.SaveAs Filename:="E:\MF\data\" & com_tick_ask & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

This is my code to save a file as xlsx but I want to overwrite an existing file.
and close this workbook.
Can anyone help...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry friends for trouble. I got an answer.

I just have to put this line of code immediately before my SaveAs statement...

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

and have to put this line of code immediately after it...

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

e.g.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
open_book.SaveAs Filename:="E:\MF\data\" & com_tick_ask & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```